# PostgreSQL - ERROR: no existe la columna «codpais» SQL state: 42703

Tags: postgresql

Hola Alguna ayuda para corregir este problema en PostgreSQL 9.6

Tengo una consulta realizada por el asistente gráfico, la cual muestra el código automático:

```
SELECT * FROM public.pais
ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC
```

El anterior código muestra los resultados de la tabla pais pero cuando hago la misma consulta sustituyendo el * por los campos de la tabla como sigue:

```
SELECT CodPais, NomPais FROM public.pais
ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC
```

arroja el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  no existe la columna «codpais» LINE 1: SELECT CodPais, NomPais
>   FROM public.pais
>                  ^ HINT:  Probablemente quiera hacer referencia a la columna «pais.CodPais».
>   ********** Error **********
>
> **ERROR: no existe la columna «codpais» SQL state: 42703 Hint: Probablemente quiera hacer referencia a la columna «pais.CodPais».
>   Character: 8**

Ese mismo error me arroja con todas las tablas de la base de datos al hacer consulta por campos, tenia PostgreSQL 9.6.4 y ahora probé con la 9.6.5 después de formatear mi pc.

Nota: En SQL Server 2016 Express funciona al 100%, estoy a punto de quedarme con mi SGBD tradicional (SQL Server); pero antes quiero ver si alguien me ayuda con este error, hasta ahora es mi único desencanto con postgreSQL.

Comment: Los nombres de columna no van entre comillas en ninguna parte, como lo tienes en el ORDER BY... Debería ser: `SELECT CodPais, NomPais FROM public.pais ORDER BY CodPais ASC`

Comment: También ten en cuenta que los nombres de columnas son _case sentitive_ , es decir, no es lo mismo `CodPais` que `codpais` o `codPais` o  `CODPAIS`. Los nombres de columna deben ser escritos **exactamente como se llaman en la tabla**.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, los campos están escrito exactamente como la tabla, tomando en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas, ya he visto varios comentarios de personas que les pasa lo mismo, en el ORDER BY si se pueden poner entre comillas, en el primer codigo los hizo el motor de PosgreSQL en automatico, yo solo cambie el * por los campos, sobre tu codigo lo puse tal cual y aun da el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba de esta manera a ver qué pasa: `SELECT "CodPais", "NomPais" FROM public.pais ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC` Si no funciona, por favor consulta las columnas de tu tabla con algo como esto y agrégalo a la pregunta: `SELECT
 COLUMN_NAME
FROM
 information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
 TABLE_NAME = 'public.pais';`

Comment: O prueba así: `SELECT "pais.CodPais", "pais.NomPais" FROM public.pais ORDER BY "pais.CodPais" ASC`

Comment: Ahora si, con este ultimo que me das si lo pude lograr, encerrando cada campo entre comillas...Crees que valga la pena seguir con PostgreSQL para un ERP de gran envergadura? no voy a programar en la base de datos, todo el código sera compilado en C#...Mil gracias

Comment: Postresql es un manejador de BD probado, robusto y útil para cualquier tipo de aplicación. El éxito o fracaso de la misma no dependerá de Postresql, sino de la calidad del programa, de cómo diseñes tus bd, tus tablas, etc. No veo problema al respecto en usar Postresql. Al final ¿te funcionó así: `SELECT "CodPais", "NomPais" FROM public.pais ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC`? para ponerlo como respuesta y pueda servir a otros que tengan el mismo problema.

Comment: Correcto con este ultimo funcionó al 100%, ahora quiero darte mi voto; pero no se como soy nuevo por aquí...Saludos

Comment: He escrito una respuesta para que tu pregunta puede tener una solución y pueda servir a otros que presenten un problema similar. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Para saber cómo funciona este aspecto de SO consulta: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: También se pueden votar los comentarios (lo que no sé es si hay que tener un mínimo de puntuación para poder hacerlo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo mismo me pasaba y tienes dos opciones.

1. usar nombre de columna en minuscula
2. si quieres usar mayusculas debes encerrarlas en comillas, una buena herramienta es `pgadmin` como interfaz alli lo entenderas mejor.

   SELECT "CodPais", "NomPais" FROM public.pais
   ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC

Answer (score 2):

Debería funcionar si escribes la consulta así:

```
SELECT "CodPais", "NomPais" FROM public.pais ORDER BY "CodPais" ASC;
```

O bien así:

```
SELECT "pais"."CodPais", "pais"."NomPais" FROM public.pais ORDER BY "pais"."CodPais" ASC;
```

Si no funciona de ninguna de estas formas, necesitarás revisar las columnas de tu tabla con una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'public.pais';
```

Recuerda respetar el *case sensitive* cuando escribas los identificadores, pues no es lo mismo  `CodPais` que `codpais` o `codPais` o `CODPAIS` o `cOdPaiS` o cualquier otra combinación.

Comment: Es correcta la primera opción. A la segunda le falta separar el alias de tabla del nombre de campo. Así: `"pais"."CodPais"`. Si el nombre está todo en minúsculas sin signos ni acentos ni eñes las comillas se pueden omitir.

Comment: Corregido. Gracias @EmilioPlatzer

Comment: Gracias efectivamente me sucedía lo mismo y era por nombres de columnas que contenían mayúsculas